# No puedo correr mi proyecto de xcode por actualizacion de librerias

Tags: typescript, ios, react-native, xcode

Buenas tengo un problema estoy actualizando mi libreria de mi proyecto los firebase esta serian las versiones

```
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "18.0.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "18.0.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "18.0.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "18.0.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/perf": "18.0.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/remote-config": "18.0.0",
```

de la version 14 pase la 18
y este seria mi podfile

```
  use_expo_modules!
  # React Native Maps dependencies
  rn_maps_path = '../node_modules/react-native-maps'
  pod 'react-native-google-maps', :path => rn_maps_path
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '14.1.0'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '14.1.0'
  pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '14.1.0'
  pod 'Firebase', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCore', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'GoogleUtilities', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseCoreExtension', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'FirebaseInstallations', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'GoogleDataTransport', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'nanopb', :modular_headers => true
  pod 'GoogleMLKit/BarcodeScanning', '3.2.0'
  pod 'lottie-ios'
  pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils'
  $RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true
  config = use_native_modules!
  
  use_react_native!(
                    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
                    # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
                    :hermes_enabled => false
                    )
                    
                    target 'Tests' do
                      inherit! :complete
                      pod 'TrustKit', '2.0.1'
                      # Pods for testing
                    end
                    
                    # Enables Flipper.
                    #
                    # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
                    # # you should disable the next line.
                    use_flipper!({ 'Flipper' => '0.78'})
                    
                    #Config para Mac con Chip Intel.
                      # post_install do |installer|
                      #   react_native_post_install(installer)
                      # end
                    
                    # Config para mac M2
                    #Firmar dependencias de manera automática.
                    post_install do |installer|
                      targetsToFix = ["React-Core-AccessibilityResources", "EXConstants-EXConstants","gRPC-C++-gRPCCertificates-Cpp"];
                      installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
                        project.targets.each do |target|
                          if targetsToFix.include? target.name
                            puts "Set development team for target #{target.name}"
                            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                              config.build_settings['EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY'] = ""
                              config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED'] = "NO"
                              config.build_settings['CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED'] = "NO"
                            end
                          end
                          target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                            config.build_settings['EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]'] = 'arm64'
                          end
                        end
                      end
                    end
                    
end
```

al hacer el build en mi telefono iphone 8

me sale este error :

```
Undefined symbols:
Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

ya intente de todo pod deintegrate y  pod install tambien cambie la configuracion en mi proyecto y busque en otras paginas la solucion y encontre que es por que compila algo que no deberia,igual no me anda no se si me falta actualizar otra dependecia de mi proyecto

Comment: Tal vez probaste poner esto $RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true justo después de use_frameworks! :linkage => :static